# Converting mp4 file downloaded via youtube-dl from periscope by using ffmpeg gives error

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, pscp, periscope

This is command i have used to download from periscope by using latest youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl -v periscopeurl
```

Then i am running this command to convert it to a proper MP4

```
ffmpeg -i gg.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p gg2.mp4
```

I am using latest youtube-dl and ffmpeg

The error i am getting is shown below

So how can i fix this error? The file can not be played properly on k lite mega codec player but it can be played on vlc player however can not go to any specific time etc. so it really needs to be properly re-encoded

```
C:\temp>ffmpeg -i gg.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p gg2.mp4
ffmpeg version N-90378-ge4eaaf7bf6 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3l
ame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-li
bvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-l
ibvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enabl
e-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 11.100 / 56. 11.100
  libavcodec     58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'gg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.10.100
  Duration: 00:56:45.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 174 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x568, 130 kb/s, 23.97 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 35 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me
=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 d
ecimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_look
ahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] frame I:1     Avg QP:19.87  size: 30456
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] frame P:36    Avg QP:19.68  size:  8765
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] frame B:92    Avg QP:25.27  size:  1149
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] consecutive B-frames:  0.8% 10.7%  0.0% 88.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] mb I  I16..4:  8.3% 10.7% 81.0%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] mb P  I16..4:  0.9%  1.5%  1.0%  P16..4: 38.8% 16.4% 11.7%  3.1%  1.3%    skip:25.3%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8: 21.5%  4.6%  2.1%  direct: 2.7%  skip:68.9%  L0:41.2% L1:45.6% BI:13.2%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] 8x8 transform intra:28.6% inter:10.9%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] direct mvs  spatial:93.5% temporal:6.5%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 74.0% 65.1% 38.7% inter: 15.2% 8.0% 2.9%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 49% 20% 23%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 12% 33%  3%  5%  5%  5%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 14% 10%  7%  9%  9% 11%  8% 11%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 24% 29% 10%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] ref P L0: 73.3%  6.3% 11.1%  1.8%  1.7%  1.2%  1.0%  0.5%  0.5%  0.4%  0.4%  0.4%  0.4%  0.4%  0.4%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] ref B L0: 94.0%  3.8%  0.9%  0.3%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] ref B L1: 97.7%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 00000009eda7ce00] kb/s:672.35
Conversion failed!

C:\temp>
```

Comment: Why re-encode it? Rewrap it: `ffmpeg -i gg.mp4 -c copy gg2.mp4`

Comment: @Mulvya rewrap not fixing the problem. it is not being displayed in media player classic correctly even after rewrap

Comment: How is it not displaying properly after rewrap?